# New Object Will Not Append To List

Tags: python, list, append

I created two lists named `dogs_list` and `cats_list` and then a third list named `animals_list`. I then tried to append another object onto the dogs_list using  `dogs_list.append('german shepards')`. After I appended german shepards onto the `dogs_list` I would assume that the list would print like 
`[['Karl', 'sugar', violet', 'tark', 'wilson', 'versace', 'german shepard']]`
But instead it returns 
`[['Karl', 'sugar', violet', 'tark', 'wilson', 'versace']]`

what am I doing wrong?

I've tried changing my command to extend and insert but nothing changes.

```
cats_list= ['karl', 'sugar', 'violet']
dogs_list = ['tark', 'wilson', 'varsace']
animals_list = [cats_list + dogs_list]
print(animals_list)
dogs_list.append('german shepard')
print(animals_list)
```

Expected:
[['Karl', 'sugar', violet', 'tark', 'wilson', 'versace', 'german shepard']]

Result: 
[['Karl', 'sugar', violet', 'tark', 'wilson', 'versace']]

Comment: `what am I doing wrong?` , your assumption is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

The `+` operation used for constructing `animals_list` creates a copy of elements in `cats_list` and `dogs_list`. The `append` call changes only `dogs_list` but not `animals_list`.

Answer (score 0):

1). After adding german_shepard to dog_list you have to modify your animal_list also. I have modified your code to get a correct result:-

```
cats_list= ['karl', 'sugar', 'violet']
dogs_list = ['tark', 'wilson', 'varsace']
animals_list = [cats_list + dogs_list]
print(animals_list)
dogs_list.append('german shepard')

animals_list = [cats_list + dogs_list]

print(animals_list)
```

Comment: ...wow, so I need to always call the array after I have appended a object inside of an array existing inside of that array? Do I always need to call the array again once I've changed or added something or does this rule only apply to arrays which hold multiple arrays?

Comment: yes, you have to call that array again which is a combination of many arrays to make changes. I hope it will help you.

Comment: @zman If you want an array that holds multiple arrays you could write `animals_list = [cats_list, dogs_list]` instead and do the concatenation only when necessary.

Comment: @GZ0 Oh I see I thought that if I wanted to add anything together no matter if it was an array, list or variables that I had to use concatenation. Now I see that this can also be done. Thank you!  :-) this is going to save me a lot oh heartache in the future.

Answer (score 0):

this is layman's approach to get the result

```
cats_list= ['karl', 'sugar', 'violet']
dogs_list = ['tark', 'wilson', 'varsace']
animals_list = [cats_list + dogs_list]
print(animals_list)
dogs_list.append('german shepard')
animals_list.append('german shepard')
print(animals_list)
```

but your solution is

```
cats_list= ['karl', 'sugar', 'violet']
dogs_list = ['tark', 'wilson', 'varsace']
animals_list =  dogs_list
for i in cats_list:
    animals_list.append(i)
print(animals_list)
dogs_list.append('german shepard')
print(animals_list)
```

this will not create any copy, you will be satisfied. you will get your desired result by this.

[image]

Comment: using + operator in list creates copy, avoid it if you don't want copy.

Comment: you will understand how python uses =, copy(), deepcopy() after you try few examples.

Comment: i know dogslist will be adversely affected.

Answer (score 0):

Check this, If I am not getting you wrong, First you create cats list then dogs list and then animals list. after that you will print animals list. Then you append `german shepard` into dogs list. It will not show you as per your expected output. If you want your expected Output like this :- `Expected: [['Karl', 'sugar', violet', 'tark', 'wilson', 'versace', 'german shepard']]` Then you need to do small change in your code. Which is as follows..

**Solution (1) :-** Try to append `german shepard` into dogs list after created dogs list.

```
cats_list= ['karl', 'sugar', 'violet']
dogs_list = ['tark', 'wilson', 'varsace']
dogs_list.append('german shepard')
animals_list = [cats_list + dogs_list]
print(animals_list)

# Output :- [['Karl', 'sugar', violet', 'tark', 'wilson', 'versace', 'german shepard']]
```

**Solution (2) :-** You can append `german shepard` into animals list.

```
cats_list= ['karl', 'sugar', 'violet']
dogs_list = ['tark', 'wilson', 'varsace']
animals_list = [cats_list + dogs_list]
print(animals_list)
animals_list.append('german shepard')
print(animals_list)

# Output :- [['Karl', 'sugar', violet', 'tark', 'wilson', 'versace', 'german shepard']]
```

To understanding concept of list you can check [here.](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp)

Comment: Actually, in your Solution 2 your output would be `[['karl', 'sugar', 'violet', 'tark', 'wilson', 'varsace'], 'german shepard']`

That's because `animal_list` is a new list, with a sublist of two more combined lists inside of it. Appending to `animal_list` would append to outside the combined lists. Dropping the `[]` when creating `animal_list` would probably be best imo